# X-editable dynamic data-pk value

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I have an element which X-editable is geetting the field from the data-pk attribute.

```
 <button class='edit' data-pk='field|value'>My Button</button>
```

I am dynamically updating this button, with another dropdown.  So that data-pk updates, to whatever field I choose from the dropdown.

The DOM gets updated as expected.

However when X-editable fires the request, its the old first-initiated data-pk value.
How can I get it to read the current value, before sending to server?

X-editable code is...

```
$('.edit').editable({
  url:'user/edit',
  // Need something here to retrieve the real current value of data-pk.  
  // not initiated value
  success:function(response,value){
       // Do success stuff.
 }
});
```

I've tried...

```
 $('.edit').editable({
  url:'user/edit',
  pk:$(this).attr('data-pk'),
  success:function(response,value){
 }
});
```

But that didnt work, also tried...

```
 $('.edit').editable({
 url:'user/edit',
 params:function(params){
    var data={};
    // Need to get this instance, and fetch the current data-pk
    // So I can set it in this data, but I have no idea how to get it.
    // params.pk just gives me the old value.  I need to get the new value
    return data;
 },
 success:function(response,value){
   // Do success stuff.
 }
 });
```

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Did you ever get a solution?

Comment: yes I did find a solution....like this
  params: function(params) {
    params.pk = $(this).attr('data-pk');
    return params;
 },

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution after a while of playing around.

```
$('.edit').editable({
 url:'user/edit',
 params:function(params){
    params.pk = $(this).attr('data-pk');
    return params;
 },
 success:function(response,value){
   // Do success stuff.
 }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

in my case

```
<span class="editable" data-type="text" data-pk="100" data-value="Value" data-language-option="turkish">Value</span>

    $('.editable').editable({
    params: function(params) {
        params.en = 'en';
        params.LanguageOption = $(this).data("language-option");
        return params;
    },
    success: function (response, newValue) {
        if(response != "OK")
            alert(response);
    }
});
```